# How can i run a long code on single button click in android without app crash?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm using an algo to download a video whenever user place Url on a EditText and hit on a Button. The algo will take some time according to user Connection speed and it will also calculate a value and taking some time in it. Everything works good but whenever I click/press the button twice app crashes so what should i need to do so it will wait until the code execute completely ?

Comment: Your question need more information and the code your are using plus the logs when the app crashes!

Comment: You have Async Task to do long processes or downloads in the background. Use flags to maintain the state of your process. Do not start the process again once your download has started and is in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question well, you dont want the onClick to be executed twice, right? One way to do this is to create a boolean (false) in the activity attributes, and then, once onClick is executed, change it to "true". For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public boolean clicked = false;

@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          if(!clicked){
            methodToExecuteYourTask();
            clicked = true;
          }
        }
      });
  }
}
```

If you need to use the button again to download, once the algo is finished, try to add in the algo a check that changes the value of the boolean to false again.
This way, your code inside the if condition will only be executed once.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in a thread that is not the UI thread. See the following code for an example of such. [Read more here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Do something in the background
        }
    }).start();
}
```